# wants to know about some Javascript function explanation

Tags: javascript, jquery, project, pixel

Hy,this is my first post here
I am following a front end dev. class
Recent task was to create a pixel art page,was my first ever bigger task with javascript,i asked around and solved parts what I didn't know how,but now I do not understand everything,would appreciate if any experienced user could help me.

```html
// Select color input
// Select size input

// When size is submitted by the user, call makeGrid()

//function makeGrid(row,colm) {
  
  function makeGrid() {
      let gridRows, cell;
     let rows = $("#inputHeight").val();
     let cols = $("#inputWidth").val();

     let table = $("#pixelCanvas");

     table.children().remove();


     for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      table.append("<tr></tr>");
     }
         gridRows = $("tr");

      for (let j = 0; j < cols; j++){
       gridRows.append("<td></td>");
      }
    
    cell = table.find("td");
  
   table.on("click", "td", function() {
       var color = $("input[type='color']").val();

       $(this).attr("bgcolor", color);
   });
}
//when size is submitted call makeGrid()
   $("input[type='submit']").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    makeGrid();
   });
```

This is my code,parts which I do not understand:

`table.children().remove();`-removes tables child element(?what exactly removes,why this needed to be implemented?

`cell = table.find("td");`-I know that .find is a jquery element which allows us to search trough descendant but I do not understand why I needed this here.

The project is also uploaded on my codepen
https://codepen.io/MelindaB/pen/xWgJqY

Thank you for the help

Comment: Could you please choose a title that describes the problem that more acurately describes what you are facing.  "Javascript Newbie would need some help/explanation" does not give us any indication of what your problem is, so a lot of users will probably skip looking at your question.

Comment: Thank you will edit the title now

Answer (score 1):

`table.children().remove();` is used to clear the current generated table to make it possible to create a new one.

You can test this by removing the line, generating a 1x1 table, and generate another 1x1 after that. You will see the grid now actually consists of 3 cells instead of the specified 1.

As far as I can see `cell = table.find("td");` has no use since `cell` is not used anywhere and this line can be removed.

Comment: Thank you for the reply,i understand now the first code,makes sense. As regarding the <    cell = table.find("td");  > I was told that my code is wrong and that I have to add this to work correctly,after adding this code I didn't saw any changes but as a beginner I just followed the crowd :) thank you your help is much appreciated